# Slight delay in vue js computed property

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js

I am trying to build a test taking system in Vue and Laravel. Once a user enters the test code and email address,they are taken to the page to take the test, so using the testcode I pull in all the test questions using a navigation guard like so:

```
beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
  axios.post('api/questions',{
    code: to.params.testcode
  })
  .then(response => {
    next(vm => {
      vm.testData = response.data //load testData object here
    })
  })
}
```

As it is a test I also want them to be able to navigate through questions using next or previous buttons. So I used a computed property to manipulate the `testData.questions` so it returns 1 questions at a time:

```
paginatedData () {
  const start = this.pageNumber * this.size,
        end   = start + this.size;
  console.log(this.testData.questions.length)

  // return this.testData.questions.slice(start, end)
}
```

Something odd happens here: `console.log` prints out 2 values: the first is an error while the second is the actual length of the questions array. Meaning there is a slight delay or so before the length of the array can be retrieved. So i used `setTimeout` to try to delay the `console.log` just to see what happens:

```
paginatedData () {
  const start = this.pageNumber * this.size,
        end   =  start + this.size;

  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(this.testData.questions.length)
  }, 1000);

  // return this.testData.questions.slice(start, end)
}
```

And now the result is just a single value (array length) and no error is printed.

What could be the cause for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The component is created and made ready before the callback in `next()` is called. If it was not, then `vm.testData = response.data` wouldn't have any effect. Therefore, `paginatedData` is first called while`this.testData === null || undefined || whatever`, then, when `testData` is updated in the `next()` callback, it is called again.

You can use a simple check like `if (!this.testData) return null` in `paginatedData` to circumvent.

[This thread](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/1144) detailes the issue.

Comment: What doesn't? Are you putting `if (!this.testData) return null` at the beginning of the `paginatedData` method? If you are, the code should never reach the console statement while `testData` is not set. Of course, if `testData` has a preset value which does not make `!this.testData` equal `false` (like a non-zero number, non-empty string or array, or an object) then the check does not work. Also, you'll need to uncomment the return statement as I believe Vue gives an error if a computed property does not return a value.

Comment: it worked!!! So brilliant, i was already looking into doing this using Promises thanks alot for the detailed explanantion and answer

Comment: Or alternatively define ‘testdata’ including correct structure but with null values in the data-property of your component. This will be overwritten with your own data as per above. Extra benefit: you have clearly outlined your datastructure which can be useful. Also, testsdata.questions (and other props you define) are now reactive